# Backbone app not initializing

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, model-view-controller, routes

I'm working on a Backbone application. I have the following app file:

```
// src/app.js
var AppRouter = require('./router');

var App = new AppRouter();
```

It's linked to the index page (the link works, I've verified that):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Feedback Dev Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the router itself:

```
var Backbone = require('backbone');
var $ = require('jquery/dist/jquery');
var IndexView = require('./views/index');

Backbone.$ = $;

var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
  routes: {
    '': 'routeIndex',
    'hello': 'hello'
  },

  routeIndex: function() {
    if (!this.indexView) {
      console.log('routeIndex called');
      this.indexView = new IndexView();
    }
  },

  hello: function() {
    alert('HELLO');
  }
});

module.exports = AppRouter;
```

When I navigate to the index of the page, the routeIndex event doesn't happen (nothing is logged to the console). Also when I navigate to `/hello`, the alert doesn't pop up either. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://backbonejs.org/#Router

> During page load, after your application has finished creating all of its routers, be sure to call Backbone.history.start(), or Backbone.history.start({pushState: true}) to route the initial URL.

Comment: That seems to have solved the problem with `routeIndex` and the index route. However, when I navigate to `/hello` in the browser I get a page saying "Cannot GET /hello"

Comment: Nevermind, I figured out why. I need to use the hash fragment URL. /#/hello works.